# How do I convert a view method to a Generic List View?

Tags: python, django, listview, generics, detailview

I have this method on the view page. It works fine and shows everything correctly but I want to convert it into a generic list view so that I could apply pagination to it.

Here is the function :`

```
#views.py
def index(request):
    all_artists = Artist.objects.all()
    all_songs = Song.objects.all()
    all_albums = Album.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'all_albums':all_albums,'all_songs':all_songs, 'all_artists':all_artists})
```

So I followed some tutorials and  ended up with this:

```
#new views.py
class IndexView(ListView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'home_list'
    queryset = Artist.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['all_artists']=Artist.objects.all()
        context['all_songs']=Song.objects.all()
        context['all_albums']=Album.objects.all()
```

Though it compiles without any error, when I render the page, the context object does not gets rendered.
Your help is very much appreciated!
Thankyou

EDIT(13-APR-17):
Thankyou guys! It finally worked with some little modifications.

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'home_list'
    queryset = Artist.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['all_artists']=Artist.objects.all()
        context['all_songs']=Song.objects.all()
        context['all_albums']=Album.objects.all()  
        return context
    enter code here
    enter code here
```

Comment: There's no need to convert to a generic view just to use pagination; you can certainly use pagination in a function based view. But *what*, exactly, are you paginating? You have three separate querysets there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

urls.py 
in urls.py from  your django app you need to include a url that references to your views and include this urls.py to your django project main urls.py.

```
#urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import IndexView

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^path/$', IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
]
```

Then in your views.py override the variable paginate_by

```
#views.py
class IndexView(ListView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'home_list'
    queryset = Artist.objects.all()
    paginate_by = 10 # Number of objects for each page

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['all_artists']=Artist.objects.all()
        context['all_songs']=Song.objects.all()
        context['all_albums']=Album.objects.all()  
        return context
```

Finally in your index.html
add the pagination {% pagination_for page_obj %}

```
{% block content %}

<!--some content -->

<!--begin paginator -->
{% pagination_for page_obj %}
<!--end paginator-->

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your get_context_data() needs to return the context. So if this is your exact code, you need to add **return context** to it